# dispatch action in _app (nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js, redux-saga

it's in _app.js where we have to connect our store and saga with "withredux" and "withReduxSaga" but, is it possible to dispatch action also in _app.js ? like that :

```
async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
      ctx.store.dispatch(fetchDataRestaurant(1));
    }
```

in my case it doesn't work, it's work only in the componenDidMount with "this.props.store.dispatch()"

My action is finally dispatching in "getInitialProps" only when I change page... when the app is loading the action isn't dispatching, someone can I help me ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try [redux-axios-middleware](https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware). It will probably resolve the issue.

```
static async getInitialProps ({ store }) {
  await store.dispatch(fetchDataRestaurant())
  return { restaurant: getRestaurant(store.getState()) }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I understand my mistake... my action didn't have a payload. Thank you.